# Receive DNS with static / fixed IP

Tags: linux, dns, network-programming

I have an embedded linux device with static network configuration. At the moment the user is forced to tell the DNS-IP via an user interface.

Is it possible to receive the DNS-IP from the network without using `dhcp`-configuration.

My application is written in c++, but I guess the question is more related to network and OS knowledge in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only standard ways (with IPv4) to get the DNS server addresses are static configuration (i.e. via a UI) or DHCP.

With IPv6 there's also the Neighbour Discovery protocol.

You *might* consider defaulting to a well known public DNS service such as Google's DNS on 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: To provide a default DNS is impossible for me, because the device/s are used in customer networks without internet connection.

Comment: @florgeng I think you're out of luck, then :(

Comment: Do you know whether it's possible to use the DHCProtocol to just receive the nameserver?

Comment: @florgeng yes, I believe that's technically possible - the client can simply ignore the lease offered by the DHCP server.  You'd still have to actually send a DHCP request broadcast, though.

Comment: (you'd also need to check that the DHCP server doesn't then keep the IP address it thinks it gave out for that particular client reserved for ages)

Comment: I think, sending a DHCP request and ignoring the provided IP isn't a valid "solution" in a foreign network environment. I think the responsible IT guys won't accept it.

Comment: @florgeng I suspect you're right.  It's easier in IPv6 where you can use SLAAC / ND to get the DNS addresses without an address lease.  Also in DHCPv6 the client has to actually acknowledge the lease before the server makes a full reservation.

Answer (score -1):

If you need static hostname - IP pairing, maybe you can use `/etc/hosts` file

add there IP and after it domainname, for example:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain
```

if it doesn't work, check if you have `files` before `dns` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` :

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hosts
hosts:      files dns
```

with this configuration is local `/etc/hosts` being checked before sending DNS requests (if not found there).